# How can I express an infinitely nested unit set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, advice

A unit set S can be expressed by $\{e\}$ where $e$ is a given element. Similarly, a nested unit set can be expressed by $\{\{e\}\}$.
Would the following notation be promptly understood as representing an infinitely nested unit set:
$\{\cdots\{\{e\}\}\cdots\}$?

Comment: Sure... I can't imagine what else it would mean.

Comment: Do note that most, if not all, theories of "sets" don't allow for a meaningful interpretation to infinitely nested brackets (e.g. by the axiom of regularity)

Comment: You're going to have trouble with that sort of thing (even ignoring the axiom of regularity from ZFC) - sets are usually only described via the membership relation $\in$, but you can't describe that purported set as meaningfully different* from $\{\ldots \{\{\}\}\ldots\}$ or any other set within infinitely many parenthesis only using membership relations - since $e$ isn't in the set, nor in any element of the set, nor in any element of any element, and so on - which is all you could possibly describe with membership. (*...or at least, there's nothing you can prove without inventing new axioms)

Comment: from a personal experience I could attest that it was not promptly understood ... even after staring at it for a little longer. (And, I am also thinking, is the outermost pair of parentheses supposed to be there, whatever that is intended to denote. What are the three dots supposed to represent? What is the thing inside the outermost pair of braces?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I think that is reasonably clear, although I think it's always a good practice to clarify notation which has the potential for being confused. So for example you could use that notation and add a line with something like "... denoting the infinite nested singleton set" or something like this. As Brian Moehring noted however, the axiom of regularity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) which is one of the ZF(C) axioms dictates that not set is an element of itself, which your infinitely nested singleton set is. That doesn't mean what you're doing is wrong, just that you can *not* construct such an object in ZF(C).